# V8 Multithreaded function

Tags: c++, node.js, multithreading, v8, node.js-addon

I'm writing a Node plugin and I'm having problems trying to call a V8 function object from a C++ worker thread.

My plugin basically starts a C++ std::thread and enters a wait loop using WaitForSingleOject(), this is triggered by a different C++ app (An X-Plane plugin) writing to a bit of shared memory.  I'm trying to get my Node plugin to wake up when the Windows shared event is signaled then call a JavaScript function that I've registered from the node app, which will in turn pass the data which originated in X-Plane back to Node and the web world.

I've managed to work out how to register a JavaScript function and call it from C++, but only in the main V8 thread.  I can't seem to find a way of calling the function from the std::thread.

I've tried various approaches, Locker objects (variable success), Persistent functions (didn't work), saving the main isolate object, entering/exiting the isolate, but if/when the code eventually reaches the function object it's not valid.

I get different results, ranging from crashing to freezing depending on whether I create various locker and unlocker objects.

I'm totally new to V8, so I'm not really sure I'm doing anything right.  The code in question as follows:

If anyone could help at all I'll be eternally grateful!.

```
float* mem = 0;
HANDLE event = NULL;
Isolate* thisIsolate;

void readSharedMemory()
{
    //Isolate* isolate = Isolate::GetCurrent();
    //HandleScope scope(isolate);

    thisIsolate->Enter();
    v8::Locker locker(thisIsolate);
    v8::Isolate::Scope isolateScope(thisIsolate);
    //HandleScope scope(thisIsolate);        

    //v8::Local<Value> myVal = v8::String::NewFromUtf8(isolate, "Plugin world");
    v8::Local<Value> myVal = v8::Number::New(thisIsolate, *mem);

    // If it get's this far 'myFunction' is not valid
    bool isFun = myFunction->IsFunction();
    isFun = callbackFunction->IsFunction();

    v8::Context *thisContext = *(thisIsolate->GetCurrentContext());
    myFunction->Call(thisContext->Global(), 1, &(Handle<Value>(myVal)));
}

void registerCallback(const FunctionCallbackInfo<Value>& args)
{
    Isolate* isolate = Isolate::GetCurrent();
    v8::Locker locker(isolate);
    HandleScope scope(isolate);

    /** Standard parameter checking code removed **/

    // Various attempts at saving a function object
    v8::Local<v8::Value> func = args[0];
    bool isFun = func->IsFunction();

    Handle<Object> callbackObject = args[0]->ToObject();

    callbackFunction = Handle<Function>::Cast(callbackObject);
    isFun = callbackFunction->IsFunction();

    // save the function call object - This appears to work
    myFunction = v8::Function::Cast(*callbackObject);
    isFun = myFunction->IsFunction();


    // Test the function - this works *without* the Unlocker object below
    v8::Local<Value> myVal = v8::String::NewFromUtf8(isolate, "Plugin world");   
    myFunction->Call(isolate->GetCurrentContext()->Global(), 1, &(Handle<Value>(myVal)));
}

void threadFunc()
{
    thisIsolate->Exit();
    // If I include this unlocker, the function call test above fails.
    // If I don't include it, the app hangs trying to create the locker in 'readSharedMemory()'
    //v8::Unlocker unlocker(thisIsolate); 

    event = OpenEventW(EVENT_ALL_ACCESS, FALSE, L"Global\\myEventObject");
    DWORD err = GetLastError();

    //thisIsolate = v8::Isolate::New();

    std::cout << "Hello from thread" << std::endl;
    bool runThread = true;

    while (runThread)
    {
        DWORD dwWaitResult;
        DWORD waitTime = 60000;
        dwWaitResult = WaitForSingleObject(event, waitTime);

        err = GetLastError();

        if (dwWaitResult == WAIT_TIMEOUT)
            runThread = false;

        // event has been signaled - continue
        readSharedMemory();    
    }
}

void init(Handle<Object> exports) 
{
    /** NODE INITILISATION STUFF REMOVED **/

    // save the isolate - Is this a safe thing to do?
    thisIsolate = Isolate::GetCurrent();
    //Launch a thread
    eventThread = std::thread(threadFunc);
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You probably need a bit of `libuv` magic to get the *main* node.js/v8 thread to execute your callback from *another* thread. This will involve:

- [A uv_async_t handle](http://docs.libuv.org/en/v1.x/async.html) which acts as the wake-up call for the main v8 thread:

  ```
  extern uv_async_t       async;
  ```
- A `uv_async_init` call which binds the uv_async_t to the V8 default loop:

  ```
  uv_async_init(uv_default_loop(), &async, async_cb_handler);
  ```
- And a event handler which will act on the uvasync_t event on the *v8 main thread*:

  ```
  void async_cb_handler(uv_async_t *handle) {
      NotifInfo *notif;
      mutex::scoped_lock sl(zqueue_mutex);
      while (!zqueue.empty()) {
          notif = zqueue.front();
          handleNotification(notif);
          delete notif;
          zqueue.pop();
      }
  }
  ```
- Finally, you'll also probably need a mutex-protected queue to be able to pass some data from the c++ addon thread to Node/V8:

  ```
  extern mutex                   zqueue_mutex;
  extern std::queue<NotifInfo *> zqueue;
  ```
- When something happens in your *C++ thread*, just push a new item to the mutex-protected queue, and call `uv_async_send` to wake up V8's default event loop (the so called 'main thread') to process the item (which can then call your Javascript callbacks)

  ```
  void ozw_watcher_callback(OpenZWave::Notification const *cb, void *ctx) {
      NotifInfo *notif = new NotifInfo();
      notif->type   = cb->GetType();
      notif->homeid = cb->GetHomeId();
      ...
      mutex::scoped_lock sl(zqueue_mutex);
      zqueue.push(notif);
      uv_async_send(&async);
  }
  ```

(Code snippets taken from [the official Node.JS addon for OpenZWave](https://github.com/OpenZWave/node-openzwave-shared))

Comment: Thanks, If I ever get the chance I'll try this out.  I'll mark it as the answer in the meantime.