# Node.js c++ addon async librarary(libvlc) callback segmentation fault

Tags: c++, node.js, segmentation-fault, libvlc, libuv

I'm trying to create wrapper for libvlc for node.js (most of them are deprecated). LibLVC generaate it's events asynchronously, but if I try to call js callback in such event, it encounter segmentation fault. I found solutions for libuv and Nan's AsyncWorker but neither can help.

Segmentation fault happens in function `on_media_player_end_reached` on 
`Nan::MakeCallback(Nan::GetCurrentContext()->Global(), Nan::New(_cb), 0, 0);`.

```
#include <node.h>
#include <nan.h>
#include <vlc/vlc.h>

namespace libvlc {

    using v8::Handle;
    using v8::Persistent;
    using v8::Function;
    using v8::FunctionCallbackInfo;
    using v8::Isolate;
    using v8::Local;
    using v8::Object;
    using v8::String;
    using v8::Value;
    using v8::Context;
    using v8::Primitive;
    using node::AtExit;

    int isPlaying = 1;

    libvlc_instance_t *inst;
    libvlc_media_player_t *mp;
    libvlc_media_t *m;
    libvlc_event_manager_t *evm;

    void Play(const FunctionCallbackInfo <Value> &args) {
        v8::String::Utf8Value str(args[0]->ToString());
        char *link = (char*) *str;

        m = libvlc_media_new_location(inst, link);
        libvlc_media_player_set_media(mp, m);
        libvlc_media_release(m);
        libvlc_media_player_play (mp);
    }

    static Nan::CopyablePersistentTraits<v8::Function>::CopyablePersistent _cb;

    void on_media_player_end_reached(const libvlc_event_t*, void *data) {
        Nan::MakeCallback(Nan::GetCurrentContext()->Global(), Nan::New(_cb), 0, 0);
        _cb.Reset();
    }

    void OnMediaPlayerEndReached(const Nan::FunctionCallbackInfo<Value> &args) {
        _cb = Nan::Persistent<Function>(args[0].As<Function>());
        libvlc_event_attach(evm, libvlc_MediaPlayerEndReached, on_media_player_end_reached, NULL);
    }

    void release_vlc(void *) {
        libvlc_media_player_release(mp);
        libvlc_release(inst);
    }

    void init(Local <Object> exports) {
        char const *vlc_argv[] = {"--no-video"};
        inst = libvlc_new(1, vlc_argv);
        mp = libvlc_media_player_new(inst);
        evm = libvlc_media_player_event_manager(mp);

        NODE_SET_METHOD(exports, "play", Play);
        Nan::SetMethod(exports, "onMediaPlayerEndReached", OnMediaPlayerEndReached);

        AtExit(release_vlc);
    }

    NODE_MODULE(libvlc, init)
}
```

EDIT: Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31207454/v8-multithreaded-function/34400660#34400660) I find out that I need to notify event loop in which node is running. Also I modified code and now I'm getting

```
FATAL ERROR: v8::HandleScope::CreateHandle() Cannot create a handle without a HandleScope
 1: node::Abort() [node]
 2: 0x12b82ac [node]
 3: v8::Utils::ReportApiFailure(char const*, char const*) [node]
 4: v8::internal::HandleScope::Extend(v8::internal::Isolate*) [node]
 5: v8::HandleScope::CreateHandle(v8::internal::Isolate*, v8::internal::Object*) [node]
 6: libvlc::async_cb_handler(uv_async_s*) [/mnt/old/home/martin/Projects/iaeste/prehravac/build/Release/vlc.node]
 7: 0x15671db [node]
 8: 0x15672b3 [node]
 9: 0x1577a48 [node]
10: uv_run [node]
11: node::Start(uv_loop_s*, int, char const* const*, int, char const* const*) [node]
12: node::Start(int, char**) [node]
13: __libc_start_main [/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6]
14: 0x8f0111 [node]
```

Modified code:

```
#include <node.h>
#include <nan.h>
#include <vlc/vlc.h>
#include <uv.h>

namespace libvlc {

    using v8::Handle;
    using v8::Persistent;
    using v8::Function;
    using v8::FunctionCallbackInfo;
    using v8::Isolate;
    using v8::Local;
    using v8::Object;
    using v8::String;
    using v8::Value;
    using v8::Context;
    using v8::Primitive;
    using node::AtExit;

    int isPlaying = 1;

    libvlc_instance_t *inst;
    libvlc_media_player_t *mp;
    libvlc_media_t *m;
    libvlc_event_manager_t *evm;

    uv_async_t async;

    void Play(const FunctionCallbackInfo <Value> &args) {
        v8::String::Utf8Value str(args[0]->ToString());
        char *link = (char*) *str;

        m = libvlc_media_new_location(inst, link);
        libvlc_media_player_set_media(mp, m);
        libvlc_media_release(m);
        libvlc_media_player_play (mp);
    }

    static Nan::CopyablePersistentTraits<v8::Function>::CopyablePersistent _cb;

    void on_media_player_end_reached(const libvlc_event_t*, void *data) {
        uv_async_send(&async);
        //Nan::MakeCallback(Nan::GetCurrentContext()->Global(), Nan::New(_cb), 0, 0);
        //_cb.Reset();
    }

    void OnMediaPlayerEndReached(const Nan::FunctionCallbackInfo<Value> &args) {
        _cb = Nan::Persistent<Function>(args[0].As<Function>());
        libvlc_event_attach(evm, libvlc_MediaPlayerEndReached, on_media_player_end_reached, NULL);
    }

    void release_vlc(void *) {
        libvlc_media_player_release(mp);
        libvlc_release(inst);
    }

    void async_cb_handler(uv_async_t *handle) {
        Nan::MakeCallback(Nan::GetCurrentContext()->Global(), Nan::New(_cb), 0, 0);
        _cb.Reset();
    }

    void init(Local <Object> exports) {
        char const *vlc_argv[] = {"--no-video"};
        inst = libvlc_new(1, vlc_argv);
        mp = libvlc_media_player_new(inst);
        evm = libvlc_media_player_event_manager(mp);

        uv_async_init(uv_default_loop(), &async, async_cb_handler);

        NODE_SET_METHOD(exports, "play", Play);
        Nan::SetMethod(exports, "onMediaPlayerEndReached", OnMediaPlayerEndReached);

        AtExit(release_vlc);
    }

    NODE_MODULE(libvlc, init)
}
```

Comment: When your C++ code crashes the first thing you do is run it in a debugger. What you're doing with that `v8::String` looks *extremely* suspicious.

Comment: The right tool to solve such problems is your debugger. You should step through your code line-by-line *before* asking on Stack Overflow. For more help, please read [How to debug small programs (by Eric Lippert)](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). At a minimum, you should [edit] your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example that reproduces your problem, along with the observations you made in the debugger.

Comment: The use of a static callback field seems suspect as well. Also, you should probably be using `_cb.Reset(args[0].As<Function>())` instead of explicitly assigning another `Nan::Persistent()` to `_cb`.

Comment: @tadman Is it, im pretty new to c++, basicali I was unable to do this in js so I tried c++ and everithing just works (onli async callbacks not), I just need to convert v8::String to char * because libuv did not eat v8::String, and as Js developer with google, that is first thing that I come up with, why is it suspicious and how to make it better ? Also I was able to run gdb, but I was unsuccessfull in creating breakpoint in addon function, even with node-gyp debug build...

Comment: @mscdex When I do as you say i get `error: no matching function for call to ‘v8::Persistent<v8::Function, v8::CopyablePersistentTraits<v8::Function> >::Reset(v8::Local<v8::Function>)`

Comment: What version of node are you using?

Comment: @mscdex v7.10.0

Comment: Your `_cb` should be of type `Nan::Persistent`

Comment: @mscdex ok now it is working (Reset) but I'm still on error in the question...